# Copying Excel data to Text File - Java (POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new to Excel - Java (Apache POI) and trying to figure out a way to transfer excel data to a text file.

My excel sheet looks something like this

```
     name   table   latest_table   Date
1   george  table1  t459           2017-08-24
2   john    table1  thi7           2017-07-23
3   mary    table1  gdr99          2017-07-22
```

My Code so far

```
public static void excel_to_text(XSSFWorkbook wb) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
         int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
         int cols = 0, tmp = 0;
         XSSFRow row;
         XSSFCell cell;

         for(int i = 0; i < 10 || i < rows; i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                if(row != null) {
                    tmp = sheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                    if(tmp > cols) cols = tmp;
                }
            }

            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(r);
                if(row != null) {
                    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                        cell = row.getCell((short)c);
                        if(cell != null) {
                            *// code here*
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have??

Comment: How is the text file supposed to look like? If your question is about how to write data/strings into a file take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Comment: How do I go about storing the data as there are of different types. Also, Is there a way to make the text file look exactly as the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is a getStringValue() method on cells. Maybe you have set the cellformat to string format before reading the string value. 
After reading the value you can store the rows and cell values in a List < List < String> >. (values)
P
Than you should find the longest string length. (k)

Call a for cycle inside a for cycle for every value and add extra space for the strings to reach k length. There are writer classes where you can define when to start a new row in the text file.